# Webpack and git in multi user mode

Tags: git, webpack

A little team with 3-4 developer with access to same files.
After each fix/update - and commit/push to server - other developers (on pull) have a problem with non-stop "merge conflict" in rebuilding bundle,chunk etc.

How to easy solve this problem? Of course - other developer (not user of webpack & js) - must do not have problem with merge conflict, or something else like this.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like you're committing the generated bundle.

In short: Don't do that. Version control systems in general should only contain *source* code, because of unnecessary merge conflicts and bloated diffs. Compilations should be part of your *build* script.